# Avoid Rad Alert Postback while Ok button Click

Tags: rad, rad-controls

how to avoid RadAlert postback after OK button Click
Server side code below

> ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "radalert",
>   "radalert('Welcome to Rad**window**!', 330, 210);", true);